# Python command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line, tweepy

I'm trying to accept command line arguments and place the values in a certain spot in my code

I'm having trouble doing so....

```
 hash = sys.argv[1]

 def on_timeout(self):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
    return True # Don't kill the stream
 sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
 sapi.filter(track=['%s']% hash)
```

I would like to put the value received as command line arguments inside

```
 sapi.filter(track=['%s']% hash)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "./twitter", line 31, in <module>

sapi.filter(track=['%s']% hash)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'
```

I simply would like to signify the terms I want to follow from the command line or another script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sapi.filter(track=['%s' % hash ])
```

Comment: I was wrong. `list` should not be used here. The first option should work